# 配達先住所の入力について

Tags: paypal

Express Checkoutにおいて配送先住所を「SetExpressCheckout」APIでプロパティに指定するのが一般的だと思うのですが、配送先住所を入手する必要が無い場合には、パラメーターに入力せずに決済手段としての機能だけを利用するという事も可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: デジタル販売したいということでしょうか。それとも配送商品だけどpaypalで住所のやりとりしたくないということでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

先のコメントにもありますが、事情があって決済機能だけを使いたいのであれば、SetExpressCheckoutのパラメーターのNOSHIPPING=1を指定すると、PayPal決済の際に住所が表示されなくなります。